# How to generate random letters (capital letters) and save into a text file in C?

Tags: c, file-io, random

How i can generate for example 100 random letters (capital letters) and save into a text file in C?
i read rand() and srand() function for generate random numbers. but for letters, i don't know what can i do:(

Comment: Please show what you've attempted. That's how this site is supposed to work.

Comment: i read rand() and srand() function for generate random numbers. but for letters, i don't know what can i do:(

Comment: To get idea of how letters and numbers are basically the same thing, check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: Is it really not immediately obvious that there's a one-to-one correspondence between the numbers 0 to 25 inclusive and the letters A to Z inclusive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

1. `fopen(file, "w")`
2. `(rand() % 26)` 100 times and `fputc('A' + your_random, file)`
3. `fclose(file)`

In this case you get a pseudo-random integral number in the range between 0 and 25.

Comment: You are welcome ;), see my last edit, the range obtained is between 0 and 25

Answer (score 2):

If `r` is a random number in the range `0..25`, `'A'+r` is a random capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Read the tutorials on generating random numbers and file I/O in C.

There are several methods you could use to generate random numbers the simplest one being `rand()`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

And for file I/O

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html

Read up on these and try what you asked. That should get you your solution.